# what does the colon greater than sign mean in coq

Tags: coq

For example

```
Record posreal : Type := mkposreal {pos :> R; cond_pos : 0 < pos}.
```

what does the ":>" mean?
I hope this isn't a duplicate, but a symbol is hard to search for.

Comment: There are other meanings to the `:>` symbol. It's better to make the title of your question more precise, unless you are interested in all the meanings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this particular case it inserts a Coercion from the `posreal` record to its field `pos`. This means you can use a `posreal` for an `R` in most cases.

Try:

```
Definition idR (x : R) := x.
Variable (r : posreal).
Compute (idR r).
```

See https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual021.html#Coercions-and-records

Comment: Ah, I suspected it was a type of inheritance, thanks