# The Coq :> symbol

Tags: syntax, symbols, coq

This is probably super trivial, but I can't find any information about what the ':>' symbol means in Coq. 
What is the difference between: 
U : Type 
and 
W :> Type 
?

Comment: It's a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41191707/2747511). I used this query to find it: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcoq%5D+colon+greater+than

Comment: I apologize for the duplication. I searched with the symbol as is, not in words "colon greater than"

Comment: No worries :) It can be hard to look for syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on where the symbol occurs. If it is inside a record declaration, for instance, it instructs Coq to add the corresponding record projection as a coercion.

Concretely, suppose that we have the following definition of a type with an operation:

```
Record foo := Foo {
  sort :> Type;
  op   : sort -> sort -> sort
}.
```

We can now write the following function, which applies the operation of the structure twice:

```
Definition bar (T : foo) (x y z : T) : T :=
  op foo x (op foo y z).
```

By using the `:>` symbol, we have instructed Coq to read the definition of `bar` as the following one:

```
Definition bar' (T : foo) (x y z : sort T) : sort T :=
  op foo x (op foo y z).
```

That is, Coq understands that every `T : foo` can appear in a position where it expects a type, by wrapping it around the `sort` projection.  Had we used `:` instead of `:>`, only `bar'` would be accepted by Coq, and `bar` would raise a type error.

Comment: You might want to add a note about Class, where it instead means existing instance.  Note also you can use > after Record to get the same effect on the constructor rather than the fields.

Comment: don't you mean `op T x (op T y z)` for `bar` and `bar'`?