# Defining subtype relation in Coq

Tags: coq, subtype

Is there a way to define subtype relationship in Coq?

I read about subset typing, in which a predicate is used to determine what goes into the subtype, but this is not what I am aiming for. I just want to define a theory in which there is a type (U) and another type (I), which is subtype of (U).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no true subtyping in Coq (except for universe subtyping, which is probably not what you want). The closest alternative is to use coercions, which are functions that the Coq type checker inserts automatically whenever it is expecting an element of one type but finds an element of another type instead.  For instance, consider the following coercion from booleans to natural numbers:

```
Definition nat_of_bool (b : bool) : nat :=
  if b then 1 else 0.

Coercion nat_of_bool : bool >-> nat.
```

After running this snippet, Coq uses `nat_of_bool` to convert `bool` to `nat`, as shown here:

```
Check true + 3.
(* true + 3 : nat *)
```

Thus, `bool` starts behaving almost as if it were a subtype of `nat`.

Though `nat_of_bool` does not appear here, it is just being hidden by Coq's printer.  This term is actually the same thing as `nat_of_bool true + 3`, as we can see by asking Coq to print all coercions:

```
Set Printing Coercions.
Check true + 3.
(* nat_of_bool true + 3 : nat *)
```

The `:>` symbol [you had asked about earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51404367/the-coq-symbol), when used in a record declaration, is doing the same thing.  For instance, the code

```
Record foo := Foo {
  sort :> Type
}.
```

is equivalent to

```
Record foo := Foo {
  sort : Type
}.

Coercion sort : foo >-> Sortclass.
```

where `Sortclass` is a special coercion target for `Type`, `Prop` and `Set`.

The [Coq user manual](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/implicit-coercions.html) describes coercions in more detail.

Comment: Thanks for your reply on both questions. What I want to do is define an algebraic theory with two carriers, one of them is a subtype of the other. I am defining the theory as a record type (please let me know if you have a better option). so for example I have: Record Foo : Type := {U : type, I : type}. I need to add the subtype relation, between I and U, but with Coercion, the super type can only be Foo. The only way I can think of now is to add the subtype relation as an axiom. Is there a better option?

Comment: You can say, for example, `Record Foo : Type := { U : Type ; I : Type ; subtype_witness : I -> U }`.  You may also want to require that `subtype_witness` is injective.

Comment: This is the closest to want I want to do. Thanks