# Making a term belong to two different types of different hierarchy in Coq?

Tags: types, coq

We understand from the hierarchy of types that `Set` is `Type(0)` and the type of `Type(i)` is `Type(i+1)`. Thus for any term `t` of `Type(i)`, it is also of `Type(i+1)`. Is it possible to have this construct in Coq? For example, suppose we have

```
                              apple: Fruit, apple : Food
```

and since fruits are food, I would like to construct types `Fruit` and `Food` such that `Fruit` is of `Type(i)` and `Food` is of `Type(j)` where i < j and thus  `Fruits : Food`. Is there such a possibility in Coq and if not are there any other ways to form something with this structure?

Answer (score 0):

In principle, it is possible to define `apple` as a type to achieve what you want:

```
Definition Food := Type.
Definition Fruit : Food := Type.
Inductive apple : Fruit :=.

Check apple : Fruit.
Check apple : Food.
```

This defines a new (empty) type constant named `apple` that belongs to `Fruit` and `Food`, as you wished.

However, I suspect that such an encoding would not be very useful in practice.  For instance, it is not possible to define an equality operator on the type `Fruit` without assuming non-constructive axioms that lie outside of Coq's core.  Moreover, `Fruit` and `Food` would be very strange types, since they would contain many counter-intuitive inhabitants; for instance, the term `apple -> apple` also has type `Fruit`.  We would need more context to determine whether this encoding would pose any trouble in your development.

(In Coq, instead of resorting to subtyping, it is commonplace to use [coercions](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/implicit-coercions.html) or subset types `{x : T | P x}` to achieve similar effects.  Check for instance [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51406898/1633770) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51470463/coq-stuck-using-the-subtype).)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The `Check` commands gives `apple : Fruit : Fruit` and `apple : Food : Food (*  |= Top.2 <= Top.1 *)` respectively when I would expect `apple : Fruit : Food` for the first one, why is that so? In your example, we are kinda forcefully making `Fruit` to be of type `Food` and `Food` is a type with `Fruit` being the only constructor. Can u also explain more on the counter-intuitive inhabitants?  My  `Check apple -> apple.` gives `apple -> apple : Type@{Top.2}`